# Date as column (Create report per day)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this query which generates the result that i have wanted.
I just need to make date into a column

```
SELECT item, date, SUM(quantity) 
FROM t 
WHERE date between '2015-08-18' and '2015-08-20'
GROUP BY item, date
```

Here is my  [**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e041/2)

which generates

[image: Output]

Result I've wanted

[image: result]

Please can anyone give me at least idea on how to achieve the result I've wanted?

Comment: probably best to do this in php consuming the original query. as soon as you expand your date range the query would have to change, application code can stay the same..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this using `conditional Aggregate`

To extract the `day` from `date` use [DAY()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html) function

```
SELECT item,
       SUM(case when day(date) = 18 then quantity else 0 end) as `18`,
       SUM(case when day(date) = 19 then quantity else 0 end) as `19`,
       SUM(case when day(date) = 20 then quantity else 0 end) as `20`
FROM t 
WHERE date between '2015-08-18' and '2015-08-20'
GROUP BY item
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e041/7)